# Selenium IDE Dropdown Menu Selection

Tags: drop-down-menu, selenium-ide

I’m brand new to using selenium ide.

I’ve gotten all other parts of my coding to work.

But I’m currently having a problem with getting it to choose an option in a drop down menu.

I have the div class name for the drop down and the

for the option I’d like to select but nothing I seem to try will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solve it using this algorithm:

```
- click on the drop-down list
- wait until list appears
- click on list element
```

or another one:

```
- click on the drop-down list
- wait until list appears
- send keys ${ARROW_DOWN} to select element of the list
- send keys ${KEY_ENTER}
```